# Is it possible to find all modules that implement certain protocol?

Tags: protocols, elixir

I was wondering whether is it possible to find all modules that have implementations for certain module?

I have a simple protocol:

```
defprotocol Ep.PerformTest do
  @doc "Should return tupple {out, time}"
  def test(struct)
end
```

And few modules that have implementations of this protocol:

```
defmodule Ep.Test.Rexcpp do
  defstruct [:input, :code, :output]

  def displayName(), do: "Rextester C++"

  defimpl Ep.PerformTest, for: Ep.Test.Rexcpp do
    def test(struct) do

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Protocol.extract_impls/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Protocol.html#extract_impls/2) appears to be what you're looking for.

> Extracts all types implemented for the given protocol from the given paths.

Thanks to OP's comment, here's what the code should look like for the example in the question:

```
path = :code.lib_dir(:protocol_test, :ebin)
mods = Protocol.extract_impls(Ep.PerformTest, [path])
```

Since we're calling the [Erlang `:code`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html) module here to get the path, the module name needs to be in the atom format Erlang uses.

Comment: As a second parameter i should pass :code.all_loaded() ?

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Based on docs
iex> path = :code.lib_dir(:elixir, :ebin) , the path contains path to the elixir devkit location

Comment: Try that and see if it works. I don't really know what the paths parameter should be.

Comment: No it doesn't but. :code.lib_dir(:mymodulename, :ebin) works

Comment: As a first param i used :ep, since my Module is named Ep.

Comment: From what I can tell, any module from your application would give the same :ebin path.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`__protocol__/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Protocol.html#module-reflection) method. From the docs:

> `__protocol__/1` - returns the protocol information. The function takes one of the following atoms:
>
> - `:impls` - if consolidated, returns `{:consolidated, modules}` with the list of modules implementing the protocol, otherwise `:not_consolidated`
> - [...]

---

**Example:**

```ex
iex> String.Chars.__protocol__(:impls)
# => {:consolidated, [Postgrex.Copy, Postgrex.Query, Decimal, Float, DateTime, Time, List, Version.Requirement, Atom, Integer, Version, Date, BitString, NaiveDateTime, URI]}
```